# Problem with importing JS Class in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

```
class driverClass {
    static #MAX_INSTANCES = 2;
    static #instances = 0;

    #_id = 0;

    static existsID (id) {
        return driverClass.#_takenIDs.includes(id);
    }

    constructor (id) {
        driverClass.#instances++;

        this.#_id = id;

        driverClass.#_takenIDs.push(id);
    }
}
module.exports = driverClass;
```

in nodejs

let driverClass = require('./driverClass');

after run I get this error:

driverClass.js:2
        static #MAX_INSTANCES = 2;

```
               ^
```

Comment: I use for private static variable in js

Comment: copy from https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-classes-complete-guide/

Comment: how do you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to upgrade node. Private static fields are [supported as of 12.0.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Browser_compatibility)

If we first modify the code to define `#_takenIDs`...

```js
$ cat driverClass.js
class driverClass {
    static #MAX_INSTANCES = 2;
    static #instances = 0;

    #_id = 0;
    #_takenIDs = [];

    static existsID (id) {
        return driverClass.#_takenIDs.includes(id);
    }

    constructor (id) {
        driverClass.#instances++;

        this.#_id = id;

        driverClass.#_takenIDs.push(id);
    }
}
module.exports = driverClass;
```

...and run it using node v13.12.0, we see the correct behavior:

```sh
$ node --version
v13.12.0
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v13.12.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let driverClass = require('./driverClass');
undefined
```

However, if we load up an older version of node, then this will fail:

```sh
$ nvm use 10.14.1
Now using node v10.14.1 (npm v6.4.1)
$ node
> let driverClass = require('./driverClass');
./driverClass.js:2
    static #MAX_INSTANCES = 2;
           ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```